# Removing activity indicator from its rect?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

I am using this code to show activity indicator :

```
    UIActivityIndicatorView  *av = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite] autorelease];
    av.frame=CGRectMake(0.5*winSize.width-winSize.width/4, 0.80*winSize.height , winSize.width/2, winSize.width/8);
    [av setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.23 green:0.23 blue:0.23 alpha:0.75]];
    av.layer.cornerRadius=4;
    av.tag  = 31000;
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector]view]addSubview:av];
    [av startAnimating];
```

and to remove it :

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *tmpimg = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)[[[CCDirector sharedDirector]view] viewWithTag:31000];
    if(tmpimg)
        [((UIView *)tmpimg) removeFromSuperview];
```

What i need is to remove only the indicator itself(the circle that rolling) and leave the rect of his view that i just draw (`av.frame`) .

How would i do that ?
Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding use this........

```
UIView * aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.5*winSize.width-winSize.width/4, 0.80*winSize.height , winSize.width/2, winSize.width/8)];
aView.backGroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
aView.tag  = 31000;
UIActivityIndicatorView  *av = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite] autorelease];
av.frame=aView.bounds;
[av setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.23 green:0.23 blue:0.23 alpha:0.75]];
av.layer.cornerRadius=4;

[aView addSubview:av];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector]view]addSubview:aView];
[av startAnimating];
```

And for remove use this

```
UIView * aView = [[[CCDirector sharedDirector]view] viewWithTag:31000];
if(aView)
{
    [aView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: I actually want to remove only the indicator, how would i do that ?

Comment: also i tried a lot to do that but i cant succeed, so i solved this problem by this way

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Build a some custom UIView that holds the background + corner radius, and holds the activity indicator as well.

After that, you can add a method to this custom UIView that hides/remove the activity indicator.

By the way, you can just hide the activity indicator, or stop it (if hidesWhenStopped is YES, it will be much efficient than creating activity indicator every time).

Comment: :) your welcome! (bevakasha!). You can vote for my answer if thats the solution...

Answer (score 1):

In that case what you can do is set

```
av.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
```

It will hide the indicator when it stops. I don't think you need to remove it.

Comment: so i can than add some buttons around that view ?

Comment: no problem. Add your buttons on that view. UIActivityIndicatorView is already an overlay view. But it will be better if you add the indicator view last.